# How did an EnumeratedSequence end up being a tuple?

Tags: swift, swift3, tuples

In the code below, (k, v) is a tuple even though enumareted() returns an EnumeratedSequence object.  Is it a compiler magic that turns it into a tuple? How can one achieve this via code - converting EnumeratedSequence into tuple?

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

for (k, v) in str.characters.enumerated() {
    print("\(k) - \(v)")
}
```

Comment: Here's the source code, for you to see for yourself: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Algorithm.swift#L74

Comment: @Alexander Useful link, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic or transformation. Nothing changes at all. An EnumeratedSequence *is* a sequence of tuples (pairs). `for` merely examines each of those tuples in turn.

So, in effect (but simplifying, because EnumeratedSequence is "lazy"), `"Hello, playground".characters.enumerated()` is already:

```
   [(0,"H"), (1,"e"), ...]
```

All you're doing with `for` is cycling through that.

Indeed, if you were to explore

```
Array(str.characters.enumerated())
```

...that is exactly what you would see — an array of tuples.

You could generate the equivalent tuples yourself; for example:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
for i in 0..<str.characters.count {
    let (k,v) = (i, Array(str.characters)[i])
    print("\(k) - \(v)")
}
```

But the point of `enumerated` is so that you do *not* have to do that; it is done for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. `.enumerated()`returns an `EnumeratedSequence` which is **NOT** an array of tuples.

The compiler magic lies in the `for ... in` statement.

`for ... in` works on a sequence and calls the `.next()` function of that sequence's iterator.

It is the `.next()` function which produces the tuple. The tuple is the `Element` `typealias` in the code below:

```
extension EnumeratedSequence.Iterator: IteratorProtocol, Sequence {
  /// The type of element returned by `next()`.
  public typealias Element = (offset: Int, element: Base.Element)

  /// Advances to the next element and returns it, or `nil` if no next element
  /// exists.
  ///
  /// Once `nil` has been returned, all subsequent calls return `nil`.
  @inlinable
  public mutating func next() -> Element? {
    guard let b = _base.next() else { return nil }
    let result = (offset: _count, element: b)
    _count += 1 
    return result
  }
}
```

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Algorithm.swift#L146